# How to do FTS within Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-search, google-search-api

Does Google Cloud Platform have a product to do full-text search via an API with non-web data (such as json or xml documents)? This may seem like a pretty silly question, but the only options I have come across are:

- Search inside of Google App Engine (only available for python2, not python3) -- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/.
- Related to web search only: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction
- Using a managed Elasticsearch: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elasticsearch.
- Cloud firestore explicitly states it doesn't offer that and suggests using Aloglia (and gives details on integrating): https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search

Is there something I'm missing? I'm basically looking to index and search about a million documents in a sort of free-form type of search. Is this offered as a product from Google outside of App Engine? If so, how can I access it?

Comment: At rest, where is your data stored?  In BigQuery, a database, GCS buckets, elsewhere....?

Comment: @Kolban it's stored in a relational DB currently.

Comment: Which flavor or relational database?  DB2, Oracle, MySQL ...?

Comment: @Kolban mysql -- but the point is I'm exporting this data to wherever the search is. For the requirements using something like MyISAM/InnoDB full text search is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much covered it there. There is currently no specific Google service for full-text search. As you mentioned, App Engine Search API is available for Python 2.7, which will [stop being maintained after January 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), and not Python 3.

There is one more option you could consider, which is [using Lucene foe GAE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gaelucene/). I found [this blog](https://medium.com/devs-foodit/how-foodit-selected-a-search-platform-within-the-google-app-engine-environment-72564f254193) where several possibilities are studied, perhaps could be an interesting reading for you.

To sum up, I would recommend ElasticSearch or Aloglia, but for the latter you need a Firebase project.